Wait to start an app running on one server until another app on another server is fully up and running
I have the following situation:

I have two Raspberry Pi's (Rpi) running in the same network
When RPi 1 is (re)started there's a service that is starting application A
When RPi 2 is (re)started there's a service that is starting application B

I want to rewrite those services on both RPi's with the following requirements:

When the service to start application A is launched on RPi 1 then the service must wait to launch application A until application B on RPi 2 is fully up and running
Application B on RPi 2 takes about 30 seconds before it is fully up and running (full startup time not guaranteed, depends on quite a few external things)
Booting up both RPi's is not synchronised.  That is: RPi 1 can start up before RPi 2 starts up or vice versa.

In systemd I know there's something like Requires, Before and After but I don't know exactly how I can wait on RPi 1 to start application A until application B on RPi 2 is fully up and running.
How can I do this in the best/most robust possible way using services?

You can't rely on Systemd solving this for you; systemd is only aware of what happens locally.
You have two alternatives:

Modify your application to enter a waiting state while checking if the service on B is running.
Write a wrapper that checks the status of B using some tool appropriate for checking if B is running, and launches application when status returns positive.

Since you give no details, it's difficult to tell you in more detail how to do either of those.

Sorry for the late reply but I went the RPC way.  This is working flawlessly with a client on one RPi and a server on the other RPi and is exactly what I wanted to achieve.
